# When can I get an Application Insights operation id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights

I have a AspNetCore web app that writes to EventHub and a webjob that reads from it. I'd like the telemetry from both parts of this transaction to have the same operation id in Application Insights.

So, when I'm about to send the data to EventHub I try to pull the operation id out of the TelemetryClient, e.g.

```
var myOperationId = MyTelemetryClient.Context.Operation.Id;
```

But this always gives me null. I found this [article](https://dzimchuk.net/post/event-correlation-in-application-insights) and tried using

```
var request.HttpContext.Items["Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.RequestTelemetry"] as RequestTelemetry;
```

But again null. Any pointers on a way I can extract this value when I need it?

My code looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection IServices )
    {
        var builder = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
        builder.Use((next) => new MyTelemetryProcessor(next));
        builder.Build();

        var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
        aiOptions.EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = true;

        IServices.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry( Configuration, aiOptions);
        IServices.AddMvc();
        IServices.AddOptions();

        TelemetryClient AppTelemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        AppTelemetry.InstrumentationKey = InsightsInstrumentationKey;
        IServices.AddSingleton(typeof(TelemetryClient), AppTelemetry);
    }
    public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory )
    {
        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseMvc();

        var configuration = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<TelemetryConfiguration>();
        configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MyTelemetryInitializer());
    }
}

[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient mTelemetryClient;

    public MyController(
        TelemetryClient TelemetryClientArg)
    {
        mTelemetryClient = TelemetryClientArg;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]MyPostDataClass MyPostData)
    {
        string telemetryId = mTelemetryClient.Context.Operation.Id; // this is null

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think I finally cracked this without creating unwanted telemetry.  The following is for AspNetCore, but should translate as long as the operation id initializer is available:

```
var operationId = default(string);
try
{
    var telemetry = new RequestTelemetry();

    TelemetryConfiguration
        .Active
        .TelemetryInitializers
        .OfType<OperationIdTelemetryInitializer>()
        .Single()
        .Initialize(telemetry);

    operationId = telemetry.Context.Operation.Id;

}
catch { }
```

Comment: If you're not using AspNetCore you can use `OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer` instead.

Answer (score 20):

I did not have `OperationIdTelemetryInitializer` in my `TelemetryConfiguration        .Active.TelemetryInitializers`.

But this provides me with the current operation id:

```
System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.RootId
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/504

Comment: Yes, Application Insights sets Activity.Current automatically so you can just use `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.Id` or `.RootId`, with no additional code or config needed.

Comment: This is not operationId this is useless ActivityId.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net core package has an `OperationIdTelemetryInitializer` ([see github](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/446b5d9ab3db283b632e13476acb8db64e38eaf0/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/TelemetryInitializers/OperationIdTelemetryInitializer.cs)) which tries to set this from a request.  Hypothetically if you have request tracking and this telemetry initializer turned on, everything that happens in that request *should* have an Operation.Id set.

if that isn't working for you, you could create your own custom `TelemetryInitializer` to set it however you need, or, in the place where you do find it to be null, you could just set it there, and all things in that context should then have that id.

Comment: Within my TelemetryInitializer the operation id is setup correctly, but it's still null when I access the TelemetryClient at the controller level. The context is different at the two different levels.
I'm using the netcore package, and I'm not doing anything to disable the OperationIdTelemetryInitializer, so I assume that's working. The actual telemetry does have an operation id, it's just I can't access it programatically where I want to.

Comment: This works, but it's a bit clunky and generates pointless telemetry:
`var dummyTrace = new TraceTelemetry("hello", SeverityLevel.Verbose);`
`mTelemetryClient.TrackTrace(dummyTrace);`
`string opId = dummyTrace.Context.Operation.Id;`

Comment: odd.  that implies that the `TrackTrace` method is assigning the `TelemetryClient`'s context to that trace, but if that is true, you should have been able to get that same context including (operation id) *without* calling `TrackTrace` from the `TelemetryClient` itself.

Comment: `mTelemetryClient.Context.Operation.Id` is `null`, so I don't really understand where the `TraceTelemetry` object gets the context from, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this value by sending a piece of telemetry and then reading back the operation id from the telemetry object. Not elegant, but it works.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]MyPostDataClass MyPostData)
{
   var dummyTrace = new TraceTelemetry("hello", SeverityLevel.Verbose);
   mTelemetryClient.TrackTrace(dummyTrace);
   string opId = dummyTrace.Context.Operation.Id;

   return Ok();
}
```

Comment: this does mean you're polluting your telemetry with traces that are only there to get an operation id? I'm still digging through source, but i have a feeling that if the context doesn't have an operation id, a new one is created and set as soon as you send that trace.  you could get the same behavior by just explicitly setting it to something yourself if it is currently null?